# Word 2016 and equation editor 3.1 - Top of the equations are cut off

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

I want to open older Word documents in Word 2016. My problem is that top of the equations are cut off. Equations are made with Equation editor 3 and 3.1.

I have tried to set line spacing to single but it did not help.

[image: An exmaple image]

[image: An exmaple image 2]

Same problem accurs if you add new equations, Add, object, equation 3.0.

Comment: Did you convert the files to the new file format?

Comment: Yes. Same problem accurs when you add new equations with equation editor 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A found two ways to fix my equations.

1. Save the document to OpenDocument(*.odt) format. Reopen the odt document and equations should be fixed. Now you can save the document back to docx format if you want.
2. Open original document with equation problems in LibreOffice. LibreOffice shows equations without cutting problems. Save document to a new docx file. Now old Equation editor 3.0 equations are coverted to new format. You may need to adjust equation placements.